# accents added around mysql functions in codeiginter

Tags: codeigniter

i want to left join one table with three conditions.
like,

```
$this->db->select('c.*, s.salary_id', FALSE);
$this->db->from('clock_i_o c');
$this->db->join('salary s', 'c.cio_thrp_id = s.salary_thrp_id AND YEAR(c.cio_time) = s.salary_year AND WEEK(c.cio_time) = s.salary_week AND WEEK(c.cio_time) <> WEEK(NOW())', 'left');
```

problem is ci automatically adds accents to the mysql functions like YEAR, WEEK.

and query becomes like,

```
...  LEFT JOIN `salary` `s` ON `c`.`cio_thrp_id` = `s`.`salary_thrp_id` AND `YEAR`(c.cio_time) = s.salary_year AND `WEEK`(c.cio_time) = s.salary_week AND `WEEK`(c.cio_time) <> WEEK(NOW())
```

i want to remove that accents. Thanks

Comment: add this `$this->db->_protect_identifiers = false;` before your query and dont forget to set it back to `true` after the query.

Comment: @DarielPratama it gives error - Cannot access protected property CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$_protect_identifiers

Comment: I would use `$this->db->query();` for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation there is a 4th Parameter 
try this :

```
$this->db->join('salary s', 'c.cio_thrp_id = s.salary_thrp_id AND YEAR(c.cio_time) = s.salary_year AND WEEK(c.cio_time) = s.salary_week AND WEEK(c.cio_time) <> WEEK(NOW())', 'left', false);
```

Fore mor information take look @the documentation [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#CI_DB_query_builder::join)